# Redux decorators get data in react component state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
@connect(
    state => ({
        data: state.data
    }),
    dispatch => bindActionCreators({load}, dispatch))
export default class Test extends React.Component {


}
```

here I want to get reducer data in react component state like this.state.data. How can I write code to get reducer data in react component state?

Comment: The data in the store is mapped to the component's props, not to the state. Use `this.props.data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using react-redux @connect , you will be getting `data` as a property in your component . To get that as a state you will have to manually  set the prop as a state in your `Component` constructor .

```
export default class Test extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){

      super(props);
      this.state = {
      data : props.data
      }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already do the mapStateToProps in the @connect, you can call `this.props.data` in the component to access the data. Hope this helps!